# Update a group of rows previusly selected with MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, transactions

I've the following problem.

I've a table INNODB on a MySql database that receives a continuous flow of data.

The table has a composite index `datetime-deviceID` a field 'data' and a field 'sended'

I'm working on a script in PHP that have to do that:

1. Select all rows that still are not sent (sent=0). (php query on MySQL)
2. Store the selected columns in a PHP array. (php)
3. Do a conversion on the deviceID (php)
4. Send the rows with an unique insert to another database.
5. Update with a single operation all the previously selected rows (point 1) and update the field sent from 0 to 1.

My problem is on point 4, I can't risk that additional data arrive between point 1 and 4, it would cause loss of data becaouse that ones will never sent to the receiver table.

In order I suppose to have to lock the table before point 1 until all the procedure is over, but I'm little new with transaction and I need some help.

I'm looking to this code to achieve my needs - am I on the right way?

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT value FROM table WHERE sended = 0 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE table SET sended = 1 WHERE sended = 0;
COMMIT;
```

Will I able to retrieve via php the columns selected form the SELECT operation or the one that are affected by the UPDATE and how can I be sure that the column of the select are the same of the update?

Comment: I suggest you to add auto_increment field to this table, so at 4th stage you can do `update table set sended=1 where ID in (...) and sended=0`

Comment: @IlyaBursov You should make that an answer.  It doesn't need to be auto-increment, but the IN clause is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions:

1. add surrogate primary key to table, make it bigint unsigned [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) (you can use [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid), but then you will need to change your insert statements or create trigger)
2. current primary key change to unique index
3. if field is auto_increment you do not need any other SQL queries to this table in your system
4. in this particular script you will need to fetch it in addition to current columns
5. store this id in separate array after sending into another db
6. on final stage you will need to execute following query: `$updateSQL = 'update table set sended=1 where ID in (' . implode(',',$sentIDs).') and sended=0';` - it will update all records with only appropriate IDs and which were not sent (actually second condition is optional, just my habit)

Comment: I'll give a try to your method but is there any way to do it with transactions?

Comment: @user2879565 you can use transactions with this method of course